# TSQL bulk update with select subquery

Tags: t-sql, syntax

I'm more familiar with Oracle so the syntax of SQL Server 2008 is throwing me.  I'm trying to perform an update of multiple rows with a query equivalent to

```
update Table
set type = 'typeA' 
where id in 
(select id from Table where type='typeB')
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Assigned_To_Email, Line 19
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Searching for a TSQL specific solution I tried the following syntax but received the same error.

```
update a
set type = 'typeA' 
from Table a
join Table b
on a.id = b.id
where b.type='typeB'
```

I've read that an update with the subquery should work, but it's not been my experience.  Is there something more basic missing here?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: The error you get is not from the queries you have included here. I think you have simplified your actual queries a bit too much. My guess is that you use a sub-query to get the value you assign to type or the value you compare with type and it is that sub-query that generates the error because it returns more than one row.

Comment: Yes, the subquery returns more than one row but this is not (should not) be an error... but, you're right, the issue was related to a trigger which was executing a statement that errored due to the multiple rows.  I appreciate your comment since it led me to the actual issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update statement does not have to use a sub-query or a join.

```
update Table
set type = 'typeA' 
where type = 'typeB'
```